# How to Retrieve Input from User Control without using Events

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls

I have a very Unusual situation.  I need to show a User Control on a Form to get the users input.  But I would like to not have to try and retrieve the information through events.  The reason is that it splits up my code to do one thing into three different methods and I would like to try and prevent that.  If there is a way I can do this, that would be awesome.

I have tried using byRef variables but because they are both in the UI thread my UserControl does not get shown.

Thank you in advance

**Window**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:me="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel >
        <Button Name="btnTest" Click="btnTest_Click" Content="Click Me!" />
        <Button Name="btnTest2" Click="btnTest2_Click" Content="Click Me Too!" />
    </StackPanel>

    <me:ucInputBox x:Name="Input" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

**User Control**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucInputBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="InputBox">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="4" BorderThickness="2">
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#ECECEC" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#CECECE" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid >
    <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.5"/>
    <Border
        MinWidth="250"
        Background="WhiteSmoke" 
        BorderBrush="Black" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel >
            <TextBlock Name="txbInput" Margin="10" Text="Input Box:" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Cambria" />
            <TextBox MinWidth="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="InputTextBox" Width="210" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0">
                <Button x:Name="OKButton" Content="Ok" Margin="5" Click="OKButton_Click" IsDefault="True" Height="30" Width="50"/>
                <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Margin="5" Click="CancelButton_Click" IsCancel="True" Height="30" Width="50" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

**Code Behind**

```
Class MainWindow 
#Region " Split Method"
Private Sub btnTest_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    '\\\\\\\\\ Button using split method
    Input.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
End Sub

Private Sub Input_Submit(Response As String) Handles Input.Submit
    '\\\\\\\ since this is the event all code that depends on the input goes here.
    '\\\\\\\ If Multiple methods need input this blows up
End Sub
#End Region


Private Sub btnTest2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Input.HandledLocally = True
    '\\\\\\\\\ This method gets stuck and never shows becuase the while loop is in the UI thread
    Dim holder = Input.GetInput()

End Sub
End Class
```

**Code Behind User Control**

```
Public Class ucInputBox
Public Event Submit(ByVal Response As String)

Private _TextBoxString As String
Public Property TextBoxString() As String
    Get
        Return _TextBoxString
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _TextBoxString = value
        txbInput.Text = _TextBoxString
    End Set
End Property

Private _WaitingForInput As Boolean = True
Public Property WaitingForInput() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _WaitingForInput
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _WaitingForInput = value
    End Set
End Property

Private _HandledLocally As Boolean
Public Property HandledLocally() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _HandledLocally
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _HandledLocally = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function GetInput() As String
    InputBox.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    While Not WaitingForInput
        '\\\\\\ Wait for input
    End While
    Dim ret As String
    ret = InputTextBox.Text
    InputTextBox.Text = String.Empty
    Return ret
End Function

Private Sub CancelButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    InputBox.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
    InputTextBox.Text = String.Empty
    If HandledLocally Then
        WaitingForInput = False
    Else
        RaiseEvent Submit(String.Empty)
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub OKButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    InputBox.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
    If HandledLocally Then
        WaitingForInput = False
    Else
        RaiseEvent Submit(String.Empty)
        InputTextBox.Text = String.Empty
    End If
    'RaiseEvent Submit(String.Empty)
    'InputTextBox.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    txbInput.Text = _TextBoxString
    InputTextBox.Focus()
    OKButton.IsEnabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub InputTextBox_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs) Handles InputTextBox.TextChanged
    If InputTextBox.Text.Trim <> String.Empty Then
        OKButton.IsEnabled = True
    Else
        OKButton.IsEnabled = False
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have now that doesn't work, and what it would look like if you split it up into different methods? Kinda hard to ride a bike with blindfolds on.

Comment: You can doing using Bindings. But first of all @Brandon said, Share the code which you tried.

Comment: @Ganesh, I have add the requested code

Comment: Try MVVM.. You can have the full control of all the Inputs in one ViewModel... Create a ViewModel common for both the UserControl and Window and bind to the DataContext of the MainWindow then you will get the inputs in the ViewModel. Bind all the textboxes to properties of the viewmodel and add commands to all the button and handle the click event of buttons using commands.

Comment: unfortunately I am unable to do that due to time constraints.  Thank you for the advice anyway though.

Comment: Just out of interest, why is splitting the code up into multiple subs a bad thing in your opinion?  Breaking code up so it's more readable instead of a massive wall of text is Software Development Discipline 101.

Comment: @JonathonCowley-Thom While yes splitting up the text in subs makes it easier to read, the sub that is catching the event has to be handled to account for each use of the control.  I try to re-use controls that i already have, if i can, to make the xaml easier to read.